# PowerShell, replacing headers where replacement is the same name but in lowercase

Tags: powershell, header

At the moment I have this code to replace all the headers of my csv file.

```
$Csv = Import-Csv "$treatmentfolder\2_1_traitement.csv"
$OldColumnHeaders = "Avis,N° invent.,Cd.Srv.Cl.,NumOrdre"
$NewColumnHeaders = "avis","num_inventaire","cd_srv_cl","num_ordre"
$i=0

ForEach ($header in $OldColumnHeaders){
    if ($header -ne $NewColumnHeaders[$i]){
        $Csv |
            Select-Object *,@{n=$NewColumnHeaders[$i]; e={$header} } -Exclude $header |
            Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "$treatmentfolder\2_1_2_traitement.csv"
        (gc "$treatmentfolder\2_1_2_traitement.csv") |
            % {$_ -replace '"', ""} |
            out-file "$treatmentfolder\2_2_traitement.csv" -Fo -Encoding UTF8
        $Csv= Import-Csv "$treatmentfolder\2_2_traitement.csv"
    }
    $i += 1
}
```

The problem that I have is that I have an error that says that the "avis" already exists as a column header even though the values are different with the uppercase and lowercase 'a'. How can I change replace this header then?

Comment: Treat the csv as a textfile and exchange the first line.

Comment: Not the most elegant, but arguably the most efficient way to do this.